# How to define a metric on a complex sphere?

Tags: geometry

The complex sphere is defined by
$CS^n=\{(z_1,z_2,\cdots,z_{n+1})\in\mathbb{C}^{n+1}:z_1^2+z_2^2+\cdots+z_{n+1}^2=c, c\in\mathbb{C},c\neq0\}$.
Could there be a metric defined on it?
And if so, what should be the form?

Comment: There is a metric: As $C\mathbb S^n$ is smooth, it has an induced metric from $\mathbb C^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the short answer is, yes. Yes we can.

A slightly longer answer begins with the following question:

What do you mean by a metric?

There are two possible notions of metric that you could be referring to: A metric is a function $d : X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ such that... or a metric (a Reimannian metric) is an element of $T^*X \otimes T^*X$. No matter which notion you mean, however, we can still produce such a metric.

The gist is that the set you have described is a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$, and so inherits a metric (in the second sense) from the canonically defined Riemannian metric on $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ given by
$$
dx_1^2 + dy_1^2 + \cdots + dx_{n+1}^2 + dy_{n+1}^2
$$
Anyhow, since we have a canonically defined Riemannian metric, we have a notion of geodesics. Using those, we can define a metric in the normal sense.

So yes, there is a metric (in either sense) on the space you have described.

Comment: Is there any difficulty in simply inheriting the metric (in the first sense) from $\mathbb C^{n+1}$, that is, $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|$?

Comment: Ah, that's maybe even a simpler answer. No, there is no difficulty with that. If you think of the axioms of a metric, then they still hold for any subset of the original metric space. So it would naturally inherit a metric just fine. It is perhaps less *natural* than the process I described above, but it is 100 percent correct.